# How to order the right way to include multiple groups in a single results set?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a contacts table with priority column.
Priority values are 1-3.
I want to select contacts 12 contacts and it should list contacts of all priorities here - 4 contacts with priority 1, 4 - with priority 2 and 4 - with priority 3.

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | PRIORITY |
-----------|-----------|----------|
A          | AB        | 1        |
qwerty     | AB        | 1        |
Efr        | AB        | 1        |
University | AB        | 1        |
United     | AB        | 2        |
Art        | AB        | 2        |
Falco      | AB        | 2        |
Some       | AB        | 2        |
123        | AB        | 3        |
Greeb      | AB        | 3        |
Greea      | AB        | 3        |
Greem      | AB        | 3        |
```

If I do just ORDER BY priority, it will give me, obviously, only contacts with priority 1 first and then the others.

I thought that I can use the PostgreSQL window function here, but not sure, still if it can be done.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT
    first_name, last_name, priority, created_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY priority ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS rank FROM contacts
  ) c
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Instead of using `LIMIT`, you need to restrict the result set to only records whose row numbers are less than or equal to 4 (for each priority partition).

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, priority, created_at
FROM
(
    SELECT c.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY priority ORDER BY created_at) AS rn
    FROM contacts c
) t
WHERE rn <= 4;
```